# How to add style to a component with styled component react?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to add style to a component.

It works fine with a component imported from the `material-ui` library, but it doesn't work when it comes to my original component(that is not used in any library).

Here is the code for style with `styled-component`

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import List from "./List";
import AcUnitIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AcUnit";

export const ListCotainer = styled(List)`  // doesn't apply style
  margin: 100px;
  color: pink;
`;

export const Container = styled.div`   // applies style
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
`;

export const Icon = styled(AcUnitIcon)`  // applies style
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  ${Container}:hover & {
    background-color: green;
  }
`;
```

App.js

```
import { ListCotainer, Container, Icon } from "./styles";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ListCotainer />
      <Icon />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

List.js (regular component with no library)

```
import React from "react";

const List = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello styled component</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Is there any way I can add style to the `List` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create styled CSS same as you have created for Container in your App.js. i have update your code it should work for you.

styles.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import AcUnitIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AcUnit";

export const ListCotainer = styled.div`
  margin: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  color: pink;
`;

export const Container = styled.div`
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
`;

export const Icon = styled(AcUnitIcon)`
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  ${Container}:hover & {
    background-color: green;
  }
`;
```

List.js

```
import React from "react";
import { ListCotainer } from "./styles";

const List = () => {
  return (
    <ListCotainer>
      <h1>Hello styled component</h1>
    </ListCotainer>
  );
};

export default List;
```

App.js

```
import { Container, Icon } from "./styles";
import List from "./List";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <List />
      <Icon />
    </Container>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to style like this component and what you are applying to the style material component is a `svg/icon` that you can apply to icons and img with style components.

style.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import AcUnitIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AcUnit";

export const ListCotainer = styled.div`
  margin: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  color: pink;
`;

export const Container = styled.div`
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
`;

export const Icon = styled(AcUnitIcon)`
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  ${Container}:hover & {
    background-color: green;
  }
`;
```

App.js

```
import { Container, Icon } from "./styles";
import List from "./List";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <List />
      <Icon />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

List.js

```
import React from "react";
import { ListCotainer } from "./styles";

const List = () => {
  return (
    <ListCotainer>
      <h1>Hello styled component</h1>
    </ListCotainer>
  );
};

export default List;
```